# Yours vs. your's

Tags: possessives, apostrophe

Which is correct *“Is that yours?”* or *“Is that your’s?”*?

I ask because it is possessive, so I would think it would be the latter, but I typically use and see the former usage.

Are there particular cases in which one should be used instead of the other? Or is one simply correct and the other not?

This is one of the few things that still confuse me, so help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: There is no such word as ****your’s***.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

It would definitely, unequivocally, and undeniably be *yours*. Same with *ours*. No apostrophe needed, and if you put one in, dark things may happen.

From NOAD:

> **yours** |yôrz; yoŏrz|
>   *possessive pronoun*
>
> **1** used to refer to a thing or things belonging to or associated with the person or people that the speaker is addressing : *the choice is yours | it's no business of yours.*

Comment: Thanks for the clarification there, it's just something that's always confused me and I always thought I was doing it correctly but never quite sure.

Comment: @Andrew Marshall: One easy way to remember this is to keep in mind this fact: none of the possessive pronouns have an apostrophe.  (*my, your, his, her, its, our, their* or *mine, yours, his, hers, ours, theirs*).

Comment: Dark things...?

Comment: @pinkpanther: "Dark things" as in you may be marked off on schoolwork, or thought sub-literate by employers and associates.

Comment: @Kosmonaut: More accurately, none of the **definite** possessive pronouns have an apostrophe. **Indefinite** possessive pronouns do: *one's, someone's, somebody's, each other's,* etc.