# Is the possessive of "one" spelled "ones" or "one's"?

Tags: orthography, pronouns, possessives, apostrophe, saxon-genitive

I've been confused about this as long as I can remember. Should it be:

> One should do ones duty.

or

> One should do one's duty.

I'm guessing it should be the latter. But that doesn't sit well with the possessive pronoun 'its'. For example:

> It is its own purpose.

vs.

> It is it's own purpose.

Here, the former seems clearly correct.

Comment: Corresponding question:  [Why doesn't “its” have an apostrophe?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/22603/why-doesnt-its-have-an-apostrophe)

Answer (score 39, accepted):

The correct answer is *one's*!

All possessives get an apostrophe, **except** the standard possessive pronouns and these are:

> yours, his, hers, ours, theirs, its, whose

Apart of these, always add an apostrophe.

Comment: Note also that "ones" is always incorrect, because a noun with an explicit singular meaning should not be pluralized.  "Ones" would be similar to "Is" instead of "us," or "yous," "hes," or "shes," instead of "them."

Comment: @Bacon Did you see the frightened ones? (Goodbye Blue Sky)

Comment: @user9325 Fair enough.  *Almost* always incorrect.  It would have to refer to a multitude of singular objects which are called a "one", which is a somewhat unusual case.  Still, I'm not convinced it's not incorrect.  "Frightened people" would be more correct.  It's not like Roger Waters was an Oxford professor.  The only other case I can thing of is when 'one' is the name of the object, i.e., "four ones" for four one-dollar bills.

Comment: @Bacon: And the Great Old Ones are Great Old People, too? :)

Comment: @Bacon @user9325 - The Young Ones.

Comment: @Bacon It's not so uncommon. Try these: "Son, would you like the purple ones or the blue ones?" "Wow, (pointing at animals) look at the little ones!" Saying "almost always incorrect" is incorrect.

Comment: @Erik @Karl @user9325 I'm going to have to go look this up some more.  I've been taught by several teachers that 'ones' as a pronoun is explicitly wrong, but clearly that's not the case.

Comment: It is not logical that "one's" has an apostrophe and "its" does not.  They are formed the same way as other possessives, while the others are distinct words.  Would plural "ones" possessive be "ones'" then?  "The young ones' music"?

Comment: @endolith - 1) This is English we're talking about; you expected logic? <g>  As stated in the answer, there are six "standard" (by which we mean "irregular") pronouns; apart from those, you should add an apostrophe.  Try not to think too hard about why those six are different from all the others - you'll only make yourself old before your time.  2) Yes, "the young ones' music makes me angry and gives me a headache" is correct.

Comment: don't even mention "whose" :(

Answer (score 6):

### Indefinite pronouns like *one* and *somebody*: *one's, somebody's*

The possessive of the pronoun *one* is spelled *one's.* There are many types of pronouns. Unfortunately, people explaining the mnemonic for remembering the spelling of *its* sometimes over-simplify and say something like "it doesn't have an apostrophe because it's a pronoun, like *his* or *her*". But actually, as already mentioned, there are many pronouns that have possessive forms ending in *-'s.* The pronoun *it* belongs to a particular *subset* of pronouns that have irregular (or at least irregularly spelled) possessive forms.

[RiMMER](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/6509/rimmer)'s [answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/26327/ones-or-ones-which-is-the-correct-usage/26328#26328) describes *[yours](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/13625/yours-vs-yours), his, hers, ours, theirs, its* as  "standard" possessive pronouns. For some people, it might help to think of this instead in terms of "definite pronouns" and "[indefinite pronouns](http://www.k12reader.com/term/indefinite-pronouns/)".

The **definite pronouns** *you, he, she, it, we, they* have possessive forms that are spelled without an apostrophe even though they end in "s". (Some definite pronouns have possessive forms that don't even end in "s", such as *my/mine, her, our, their*.)

But the more numerous **indefinite pronouns** (*one, someone, somebody, nobody, another,* etc.) take the usual *-'s* to mark the possessive.

Not all pronouns belong to either of these two categories. As [tenfour](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/4929/tenfour) mentioned in a [comment](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/26327/is-the-possessive-of-one-spelled-ones-or-ones#comment74909_26328), there's also the **interrogative and relative pronoun** *who* which has the irregularly spelled possessive form *whose.*

### How *one* and *one's* is different from other indefinite pronouns

The possessive of *one* (*one's*) is *formed* the same way as the possessive of other indefinite pronouns, such as *someone* (*someone's*), but it is *used* a bit differently. For most people, *one* is consistently used with the possessive form *one's.* Other indefinite pronouns can (in fact, must) be referenced in some situations with the possessive form of a third-person definite pronoun like *his, her* or *their.* Here's an example of what I mean:

- ***Someone*** left **his/her/their** hat on the table.
- ***No one*** likes to have **his/her/their** word doubted.

We don't use *someone's* or *no one's* in this context (i.e., to refer back to an earlier use of *someone* or *no one* in the same sentence). However, many people *would* say the following sentence:

> - ***One*** does not like to have **one's** word doubted.

—*A Dictionary of Modern English Usage,* by H. W. Fowler ([OUP's "Classic" First Edition](https://books.google.com/books?id=hrtIDakUpA4C&pg=PT940&lpg=PT940&dq=one%20%22oneself%22%20%22himself%22%20reflexive%20fowler&source=bl&ots=ZT2d3TB3qJ&sig=BfwDzcfazRbAZKSp3D9VPmeTaDM&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwirjLaUxOLOAhVM7GMKHZkKBwUQ6AEIUTAI#v=onepage&q=one%20%22oneself%22%20%22himself%22%20reflexive%20fowler&f=false))

The linked passage in Fowler mentions that "**One** does not like to have **his** word doubted" also existed in his time as a competing form. I don't know to what extent modern writers use *his* (or perhaps *their*) in sentences like this, but it's definitely less common than *one's.*

Another way *one* is unlike the other indefinite pronouns is that it has a special reflexive form, *oneself.*