# correct use of yours, possive

Tags: word-usage, punctuation

Is this sentence correct; "Thank you for your letter about the missing items in both yours’ and your mother’s homes"?

Answer (score 2):

The apostrophe in **yours'** is incorrect. See [this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/13625/yours-vs-yours) for a good explanation.

Otherwise the sentence is correct, but it's open to several interpretations. It might be clearer, albeit more long-winded, to rewrite it thus:

> Thank you for your letter about the items missing from your home and from your mother's home.

**Update:**

As well as the apostrophe in **yours'** being incorrect in the OP's sentence, the word **yours** is itself incorrect. It should be **your**.

Comment: The _apostrophe s_ is incorrect here.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - do you mean the apostrophe in mother's?

Comment: You say that the apostrophe needs dropping from yours'. But, as shown in your expanded version, the possessive determiner _your_ is needed here.

Comment: Ah, I thought you were referring to my sentence, not the OP's. I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your is a possessive adjective .

Your car is black!

Yours, however is a possessive pronoun .

That car of yours is black!

Though you may see your’s written even by native speakers, it is incorrect.

Yours should never have
an apostrophe.

Comment: But should it be _your_ or _yours_ here?

Comment: I think you have used apostrophe with yours' which is incorrect...

Comment: "Thank you for your letter about the missing items from yours and your mother’s homes"?

Comment: I'm not aware of having used any apostrophes here. You haven't answered which is correct: "Thank you for your letter about the missing items in both yours and your mother’s homes" or "Thank you for your letter about the missing items in both your and your mother’s homes"?

Comment: The correct one is "Thank you for your letter about the missing items in both yours and your mother’s homes"?

Comment: Would you say "Thank you for your letter about the missing items in both hers and your father's homes" ?