# Yours sincerely or Your's sincerely

Tags: orthography

Yours sincerely or Your's sincerely
which one is correct when yyandou write complimentary close and how?

Comment: Your question is also related to [Yours vs. your's](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/13625)

Comment: sumelic's link has what you seek.  The apostrophe distinguishes possessives from plurals; and since pronouns do not (in normal use) use an 's' for plurals, they don't need an apostrophe to mark possessives.